# Segue from Swift to Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm trying to implement a segue from one view to another. It works fine from one swift class to another, but from a swift class to an objective-c class, I get the error:

> Use of undeclared type 'ReordViewController'

**Code:**

```
if (templateList?.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as NSString != "Story") {
        var dvc : TemplateViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TemplateViewController") as TemplateViewController
        dvc.tweet = templateList?.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as NSString
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(dvc, animated: true)
    }
    else {
        var dvc : RecorderViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("RecorderViewController") as RecorderViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(dvc, animated: true)
    }
```

**Edit:**

To clarify, TemplateViewController is in Swift and RecorderViewController is in Objectivce-C.

Comment: This suggests that you have either not created the bridging header correctly, or failed to include your Objective-C class header in that bridging header.

Comment: I used the automatic bridging header that was suggested when I imported the classes from another project. Is that not a good idea?

Comment: Yep, it may prompt you to create the bridging header, but it doesn't automatically import your own headers there. You have to do that. Include the `#import "RecorderViewController.h"` (or whatever) in that bridging header.

Comment: Oh you are right!! I didn't realize I had to add it to the header... I thought it was automatic. Thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create a bridging header (it will often automatically prompt you to create one when you include Objective-C class in Swift project or vice versa) and then make sure to manually include a `#import` line for your Objective-C class header in the bridging header file:

```
#import "RecorderViewController.h"
```

See [Swift and Objective-C in the Same Project](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-XID_78) discussion.